# Navbar contents do not load in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

The NavBar content loads fine in mobile view however, when a link is clicked from the contents and i try to load the navbar again, the contents do not load. In short, the contents only load once, and not again when something has been clicked.

I have tried editing the JS but as i'm still learning web development, its quite hard. You can see the navbar on a codepen i have created https://codepen.io/Jaderianne/pen/MMRpqa

```
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
  if (link.style.animation) {
    link.style.animation = '';
  } else {
    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 
0.5}s`;
  }
});
burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
});

const closeNav = () => {
nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
}
navLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', closeNav));

}

navSlide();
```

I expect the navbar to load the content when the "burger" is clicked, even after something has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `if (link.style.animation)` line is the problem here. 
You can try printing the `link.style.visibility` inside the forEach loop to see what I'm talking about.

Whenever you open the nav-bar, `link.style.animation` being set, and not being unset whenever the nav-bar is closed.

To quick-fix this in your code - whenever you close the navigation, you'll need to reset the animation property. Replace the existing `closeNav` function with this -

```js
const closeNav = () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    // New code
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.style.animation = '';
    });
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNyROr) that does this.

NOTE: This solution assumes that you'd want to do this with JS only (since you mentioned that you're learning). I'd recommend checking out [CSS keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) for this sort of thing, since I believe that'll be a bit more easier.

Answer (score -1):

remove  this css

```
 .nav-links li {
          opacity: 0;
        }
```